# Is there a Java equivalent of Python's dictionary display?

Tags: java, dictionary

In Python I'm using a dictionary display:

```
myAnonDict = {'foo': 23, 'bar': 'helloworld'}
```

Is there an equivalent in Java?

[edited 'anonymous dictionary' to read 'dictionary display']

Comment: What is so "anonymous" about this dictionary?

Comment: You are looking for a hash table?

Comment: @van: It is just the syntax... using `dict()` instead of `{}` would be non-anonymous. I really don't know why there is a difference, a dict is a dict for me.

Comment: It is a [dictionary display](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-dict_display), not an anonymous dictionary.

Comment: java.util.Map - http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: Questions about "how to do something like the X feature of language Y, in language Z" are inherently not Y questions, and experts in Y have no special advantage in answering them. Removed the Python tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
myMap.put("foo", "23");
myMap.put("bar", "helloworld");
```

This is different from yours because yours has heterogeneous data types whereas mine deals in Strings only.  You can actually have mixed collections in Java, too, but I hate doing that.  Kind of defeats the purpose of strong typing.

Comment: @FrusteratedWithFormsDesigner: It's the same code, but without the `<String, String>` sets.  Not only that, but everything you get back out will be of type `Object`, and you'll have to cast it back to its original type.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Boo. I was hoping for a more interesting solution than just `Object` s.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner like what?  Make an answer :)

Comment: Any way to do that in a single line?

Comment: @sprocketonline some of it, but don't do that.  Java is intentionally verbose.

Answer (score 5):

[Apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi) will allow you to do something similar (a string based example; can be customized)

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;

public class ArrayToMapExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map dict = ArrayUtils.toMap(new String[][]{{"United States", "New York"},
                            {"United Kingdom", "London"},
                              {"Netherland", "Amsterdam"},
                              {"Japan", "Tokyo"},
                              {"France", "Paris"}});


        System.out.println("Capital of France is " + dict.get("France"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't have anonymous dict because 1) it is statically-typed language, 2) it doesn't have support this feature on the syntax level. You need to specify type of the dictionary during creation. In contrast, [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/), which is JVM-based language has this feature. 
You can write above code in the following way in Groovy:

```
def myAnonDict = [foo: 23, bar: 'helloworld']
```

Answer (score 1):

Closest shortcut to this form is the following hack:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
    add("foo", 23);
    add("bar", "hello")
}};
```

However, this will create an anonymous class which is not always good.

Unfortunately, java is not a language of shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

If the question was broadened from "Java" to "language running on the Java VM", this Scala code is quite concise:

```
def myAnonDict = Map("foo" -> 23, "bar" -> "helloworld")
```

One improvement over the Python syntax is that it is more readable to outsiders.

Answer (score 0):

[abacus-common][1], a general programming library in Java, which provides a lot of most daily used methods to make programming with Java more fun and more productivity:

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = asMap("abc", 23, "bar", 7);
```

(Declaration: I'm the developer of abacus-common)
[1]: https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common